# What is the ffmpeg command to convert 3gp to ulaw?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, audio-conversion, 3gp

I am able to convert it to `wav` using:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.3pg audio.wav
```

but I need the command to convert it to `ulaw`.

Anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest example is:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input -codec:a pcm_mulaw output.wav
```

Refer to `ffmpeg -encoders` to see a list of available encoders.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to have the ulaw extension instead, when I change the extensions I get `[NULL @ 0250ef00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.ulaw'
output.ulaw: Invalid argument`

Comment: what do you mean, sorry I did not get it

Comment: @meda If you use `.wav` as an extension, ffmpeg automatically guesses that you want a WAV container wrapping your PCM audio. If you do not want that, and instead need raw audio data in a `.ulaw` file, you need to use `-f mulaw` to force ffmpeg to use the PCM mu-law output format.

Comment: Ok that worked, eventhough the quality is terrible, thanks anyway